# Why $this->id inside model returns null?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I need to get model id in Eloquent model. I'm trying to do it this way - `$this->id` while calling relationship like this

`return $request->user()->load('myrelation');`.

But in this way I always get null. But, if I try this `return $request->user()->myrelation();` with `return $this->id` I will get correct model id. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of relation you are using (One to One, One to Many, Many to Many)? Here is an example of a One to One User/Company:

In User model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

You can get the company `id` using `$user->company->id`. If you call `$user->company()->id` you get `null` because `$user->company()` returns the relationship, not the model.

Comment: I need to use one to one relationship, but I also need to create and store relation to db if it not exists. So I tried to detect if relation exists this way `if(!($this->hasOne(UserSettings::class)->exists()))` which didn't work, so now I want to get model id to do something like this   `if(!UserSettings::where('id',$this->id)->first())`

Comment: Here is how you detect if a relation exists in Eloquent (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). How your db and relations are defined?

Comment: I dont quite understand your last question,sorry. I have User and UserSettings models. I will use  this relation to display current settings for user and for admin that can watch settings of every user, so I can't use Auth::id(). I want model to check if settings for this user aleady exists every time relation user->load('settings') is called . And if it don't exists to create new record with default values. I know about withDefault() method, it's exactly what I need, but it simply return relation while I need to store it do db before displaying to user.